# Exception while trying to update an JDBC ResultSet using a H2 database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2

I try to insert a row using a ResultSet into a H2 database (1.4.182). By invoking insertRow the program throws an exception. And I have no clue what the problem is.

The exception is:

```
The result set is not updatable. The query must select all columns from a unique key.
Only one table may be selected. [90127-182]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getUpdatableRow(JdbcResultSet.java:3081)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.insertRow(JdbcResultSet.java:2966)
    at JdbcResultSetUpdate.main(JdbcResultSetUpdate.java:26)
```

The SQL statement the program executes to create the ResultSet is:

```
"select NAME from TEST.TST_DOZENT"
```

TST_DOZENT is created by the statement:

```
"CREATE TABLE TEST.TST_DOZENT (NAME VARCHAR(50))", "Create TST_DOZENT-Tab"
```

So the query-statement doesn't use a system-table, the table has no primary-key.

The java statement object is created by:

```
con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

I can't fugure out what the problem is or what I'm doing wrong.

I would appreciate any help.

Thany you for reading.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory _"The query must select all columns from a unique key."_; your table doesn't have a primary key (or other unique key), so the select result set isn't updatable.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The error message is nowhere near self-explanatory. On the contrary, it is quite difficult to derive `The table needs to have a primary key or unique index, and the query needs to contain that column` from it.

Comment: @KorayTugay That is just more verbose rephrasing of what that error message says. _"The query must select all columns from a unique key."_ says two things: 1) select **all columns** from a unique key and 2) select [..] from **a unique key**. If you must select from a unique key, then logically the table must have a unique key, otherwise you can't fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok, if you say so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table needs to have a primary key or unique index, and the query needs to contain that column. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.TST_DOZENT (ID PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(50));
SELECT ID, NAME FROM TEST.TST_DOZENT;
```

Comment: What if I have PK spread across multiple columns (composite primary key)? In that case do we need to select all columns that make up the PK?